# Error Message: cannot get Oracle version from sqlplus

Tags: ruby, oracle, ubuntu, oci8

Ruby-oci8 gem is failing with the following error message while built on ubuntu linux, even though I have my LD_LIBRARY_PATH and ORACLE_HOME set to the right path.

> *Get the version of Oracle from SQLPlus... /ghostcache/nightly_build/components/ruby-oci8/akamai/ruby-oci8/ruby-oci8-2.2.1/ext/oci8/extconf.rb
>   failed Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
>   necessary libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more
>   details. You may need configuration options.

```
Provided configuration options:
 --with-opt-dir
 --without-opt-dir
 --with-opt-include
 --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
 --with-opt-lib
 --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
 --with-make-prog
 --without-make-prog
 --srcdir=/ghostcache/nightly_build/components/ruby-oci8/akamai/ruby-oci8/ruby-oci8-2.2.1/ext/oci8
 --curdir
 --ruby=/ghostcache/nightly_build/components/ruby-oci8/akamai/ruby2.1/export/bin/ruby
 --with-instant-client
 --without-instant-client
/ghostcache/nightly_build/components/ruby-oci8/akamai/ruby-oci8/ruby-oci8-2.2.1/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:834:in `get_version': RuntimeError (RuntimeError)
 from /ghostcache/nightly_build/components/ruby-oci8/akamai/ruby-oci8/ruby-oci8-2.2.1/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:783:in `initialize'
 from /ghostcache/nightly_build/components/ruby-oci8/akamai/ruby-oci8/ruby-oci8-2.2.1/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:320:in `new'
 from /ghostcache/nightly_build/components/ruby-oci8/akamai/ruby-oci8/ruby-oci8-2.2.1/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:320:in `get'
 from /ghostcache/nightly_build/components/ruby-oci8/akamai/ruby-oci8/ruby-oci8-2.2.1/ext/oci8/extconf.rb:22:in `<main>'
```

Error Message:

> cannot get Oracle version from sqlplus Backtrace:
>   /ghostcache/nightly_build/components/ruby-oci8/akamai/ruby-oci8/ruby-oci8-2.2.1/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:834:in
>   `get_version'
>
>   /ghostcache/nightly_build/components/ruby-oci8/akamai/ruby-oci8/ruby-oci8-2.2.1/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:783:in`
>   initialize'
>   /ghostcache/nightly_build/components/ruby-oci8/akamai/ruby-oci8/ruby-oci8-2.2.1/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:320:in
>   `new'
>
>   /ghostcache/nightly_build/components/ruby-oci8/akamai/ruby-oci8/ruby-oci8-2.2.1/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:320:in`
>   get'
>   /ghostcache/nightly_build/components/ruby-oci8/akamai/ruby-oci8/ruby-oci8-2.2.1/ext/oci8/extconf.rb:22:in
>   `'*

Any idea what's missing here?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I just had to create a "bin" sub-directory under ORACLE_HOME, and then create a link to the sqlplus binary there.